What is purpose of pushToStartTokenUpdates in iOS live activity
I'm experiencing difficulty obtaining the pushToStartToken required to start live activities from APNS. Although I have subscribed to pushToStartTokenUpdates, I'm not receiving any updates
Here is the code I used:
   ` Task {
        do {
            for try await data in Activity<LiveActivityAttributes>.pushToStartTokenUpdates {
                let token = data.map {String(format: "%02x", $0)}.joined()
                print("Activity token: \(token)")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }

`
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
If I create a live activity and then async call activity.pushToStartTokenUpdates ,then I can see the new token. So what is the purpose of pushToStartTokenUpdates api?
